# Drag and Drop multiple divs as unique

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i'm working with drag and drop but i stopped at this problem.

I have 2 columns and I want to drag divs from source to target column. The problem is that these source divs are reapeated in every source container and I need that when I move one (The div #36406 for example), all others divs in adjacent source containers with the same ID disappear of source column.

[image]

**edit 1:**

```js
 function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.className);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
         debugger;
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
```

```html
<div style="height:50px; width:50px; border: 1px solid blue; margin-left:40%" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> DROP HERE'</div>   <!-- Target -->


<div class="btn btn-warning '+parcelas[j].idlancamento+'" draggable="true" style="cursor:move" ondragstart="drag(event)">
SOURCE
</div> <!-- source -->
```

Comment: Could you post your current JS code? We could provide a more concrete answer that way. I think the general idea would be to add the ID to each div's class, and then hide all other divs (opacity: 0, display: none, etc) with the same class when the dragstart event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for reply @J.Chen. I edited my post with the code. Can you explain more properly how can i hide the others dynamically with ID?

Comment: element id's are supposed to be unique. If you have `div` elements with the same `id` attribute you need to fix that before you can fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I've posted a working example below. I set each div's `data-id` attribute to its ID number. I used jQuery in this example (hope that's ok). When the drag event starts, the `dragStart()` function is called, and it searches for each div that has a matching `data-id` attribute and sets the opacity to 0. The `dragStop()` function sets the opacity back to 1. Let me know if you have any further questions :)

```js
 function dragStart(ev) {
 let id = ev.target.getAttribute("data-id");
  $("[data-id=" + id + "]").not(ev.target).css("opacity", 0);
 }
 
 function dragStop(ev) {
  let id = ev.target.getAttribute("data-id");
  $("[data-id=" + id + "]").not(ev.target).css("opacity", 1);
 }

function drop(ev) {
  debugger;
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn btn-warning '+parcelas[j].idlancamento+'" data-id="123" draggable="true" style="cursor:move" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragend="dragStop(event)">
ID: 123
</div>

<div class="btn btn-warning '+parcelas[j].idlancamento+'" data-id="123" draggable="true" style="cursor:move" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragend="dragStop(event)">
ID: 123
</div>

<div class="btn btn-warning '+parcelas[j].idlancamento+'" data-id="123" draggable="true" style="cursor:move" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragend="dragStop(event)">
ID: 123
</div>

<div class="btn btn-warning '+parcelas[j].idlancamento+'" data-id="000" draggable="true" style="cursor:move" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragend="dragStop(event)">
ID: 000
</div>
```

Comment: This code gave me the correct direction for my problem @J. Chen.

Comment: Glad I could help!